# How to find specific RPi image?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I need to replicate client's RPi setup as close as possible. I have output of `uname -a` on their RPi:

```
Linux lumberjack 4.4.10-hypriotos-v7+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 20 14:49:10
UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

How do I find same or closest RPi image?

Thank you.

Comment: Is simply imaging the source Raspberry Pi's SD card an option?

Comment: may be, didn't think about it )) thanks.

Comment: Build the kernel https://github.com/hypriot/rpi-kernel